# Use firebase Auth uid as user document _id in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have user collection and want to use Firebase uid as document _id ,

```
let _id = new ObjectID('Firebase Auth uid'); // Error Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex
  let val = Object.assign(req.body, {
       _id: _id,
  });
  const user = new User(val);

  // Save User in the Collection
  return user.save();
```

Eg: Firebase Uid = `5w9WnBiUPdT2wh7bsarYBQLQDqa2`

And if i pass directly without using `new ObjectID('Firebase Auth uid');` mongoose returns

> Failed: _id: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "ThobO6kTv6aMHUa4UN3nBjkCgNb2" at path "_id"

Answer (score 5):

An [ObjectID](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#objectid) is a 24-byte value, the constructor expects a hexadecimal string.

If you plan to use strings for _id values, explicitly declare `_id` as `String` in the schema.

```
    const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
      _id: String
    });
```

Comment: If you use this approach does Mongo still index the `_id` field?

Comment: yes, it does.  There is no implicit type requirement for the `_id` field, MongoDB will accept anything you care to put there.